# Android studio remove items from both listview and firebase

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to remove items from both listview and firebase in android studio.
When I remove items from the firebase console, it automatically removes items from listview.
However I want to remove items from the listview first, and want this changes to be reflected on the database.

```
public class PreferActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Firebase Var
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

//Android Layout
private Button btnAdd;
private EditText etText;
private ListView listView;

//Array list
private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_prefer);
    mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);

    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    etText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDatabase);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.database_list_view);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mDatabase.push().setValue(etText.getText().toString());
        }
    });


    mDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            String string = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

            arrayList.add(string);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String string = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

            arrayList.remove(string);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });



}
}
```

Any comments would help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I must ask: Why do you desire such behavior?

Comment: I'm developing food recipe application. 
I need to know which ingredients user don't eat
So user types "cucumber", "pork", and so on.. in listview
When user wants to remove those ingredients from dislike list,
I want user to remove items in application directly.

Comment: Well, I misunderstood your question at first. But I understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, use the following lines of code:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
        String item = adapter.getItem(position);
        adapter.remove(item);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //Delete item form Firebase database
    }
});
```

I have added a `setOnItemClickListener` on your `listView` and remove the item from the adapter first and them from your database accordingly to the item that was clicked.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply!
Your code removes item from listview but when I check firebase, it still has items that I removed from listview. How can I solve it??

Comment: Yes, it still has that record because I only added a comment in the code above that indicates only the place where you need to remove it. So to actually remove the item you need to get the reference of the item and use `mDatabase.chil(itemId).removeValue()` method on it. In which `itemId` is the id of the item that you want to remove. To get that id, when you are adding the item using `push()` method, store the unique id into a field like this: `String itemId = mDatabase.push().getKey();`.

Comment: Thanks Alex! I changed the whole code now...:( I do not use this code any more

Comment: Do you think that my answer heleped you in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Now this solution might be hard coded, but that's because you're only storing Strings on the database while you also need their keys to tell firebase which one to delete. My recommendation is having a second `ArrayList` to store the keys and access it on Item Click.

So first you declare this `ArrayList`, let's name it `keysList`:

```
private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> keysList = new ArrayList<>();
```

then you must change your `onChildAdded` method to store those keys in the `ArrayList`:

```
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            String string = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

            arrayList.add(string);
            keysList.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

But then you'd also have to change your `onChildRemoved` to remove the deleted keys from the `keysList`:

```
        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String string = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

            arrayList.remove(string);
            keysList.remove(dataSnapshot.getKey());

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

And finally, add an `onItemClickListener` to your `listView` so that the user can click to remove the item from Firebase:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                String key = keysList.get(position);
                mDatabase.child(key).removeValue();
            }
        });
```