# How to delete item from firebase list adapter and firebase using button

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have an activity that reads data from firebase database and displays the data in a firebase list adapter. Each item in the list view has 2 edit text and a button for deleting the item from both the list view and the firebase database. Below is the code for displaying the firebase list adapter

```
      adapter =new FirebaseListAdapter <TravelDetails>
   ( options){
  protected void populateView(View v, TravelDetails model, int position) {
Button delete=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button_accept);
final TextView z=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.dropoff);
final TextView text=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txref);
text.setText(model.getTxt_Ref());
 z.setText(model.getDropoffspot());
 delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {.....
```

The list view works fine. Data is loaded from firebase, but 
I want to be able to use this button delete to delete items from both the list view and firebase database. I did research and only found ways on item click and not using a button, an example is this [Android studio remove items from both listview and firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48246504/android-studio-remove-items-from-both-listview-and-firebase)  but I don't know how to apply the principle to the button associated with the item from the database . Kindly render assistance

Below is the code of my adapter class
               public class TravelDetails {

```
    private String dropoffspot;
    private String txt_Ref;

    public TravelDetails(){

    }


    public String getDropoffspot(){
    return dropoffspot;
     }
    public void setDropoffspot(String dropoffspot){
    this.dropoffspot=dropoffspot;
    }

    public String getTxt_Ref() {
    return txt_Ref;
    }

       public void setTxt_Ref(String txt_Ref) {
       this.txt_Ref = txt_Ref;
     }

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to solve my problem. I simply add this in the delete buttons on click method.

```
         public void onClick(View v) {
         DatabaseReference item=adapter.getRef(position) ;
         item.removeValue();
```

} 
}) ;

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way inside your adapter

```
// make this function inside your adapter

protected void populateView(View v, ArrayList<TravelDetails> models, final int position) {
    Button delete=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button_accept);
    final TextView z=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.dropoff);
    final TextView text=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txref);
    text.setText(model.getTxt_Ref());
    z.setText(model.getDropoffspot());
    delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // code to delete from firebase
            models.remove(position); // delete from adapter array list
            notifyDataSetChanged(); // refresh adapter
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am now getting a cannot resolve method getTxt_Ref() as well as cannot resolve method getDropoffSpot.

Comment: As well as error 'class anonymous class derived from Firebase list adapter must either be declared abstract or implement method populateview (View, T, int) in firebase list adapter' this is under the code, 'adapter =new FirebaseListAdapter <TravelDetails >(options)...

Comment: I still await your response

Comment: can you plz show complete code of adapter class. you can update code in question.

Comment: You mean the TravelDetails class am using?

Comment: I have added the class. My apologies for the delay I accidentally added the class to your answer at first